# Why we consider identical particles for Bose-Einstein condensation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate

Why we consider identical particles like identical composite bosons for BEC.  Why we do not consider non identical particles of differnt masses etc?

Comment: Look up the definition of a thermodynamic ensemble. The usual framework for BEC theory is quantum statistics, where you CAN consider a mixture of different spices, but it won't bring in much new physics in play, while generating substantial analytical complications...

Answer (score 1):

The irreducible representations of the Poincaré group are labelled by mass $m$ and the spin $s$. 
 So as soon you have particles that have different mass, they are intrinsically *different* and obey their own Bose/Fermi/... statistical distribution.

I assume here that you do not mean *idential* to be a synonym of *indistinguishable*. If yes, please clarify.

Comment: Here we are taking identical and indistinguishable in a same meaning.

Comment: Okay. Does the answer not satisfy you?